# Interpreting/understanding the lambertW on Maple software

Tags: maple, lambert-w, symbolic-computation

I decided to use the Maple software to help me solve dynamic optimization problems, and I found this final solution for T. (example in the picture).
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a164C.png)

What does the LambertW mean for the solution T? Can I get rid of this expression to express T in simple terms? Does theLambertW (including the expression inside it) have a solution or an equivalent expression? If this is the final form, I assume I can no longer proceed with symbolic/analytical solution, and I must move to computation?

Comment: Lambert W is the inverse of $xe^x$.  That is: $W(a)=b \Longleftrightarrow a=be^b$.

Answer (score 1):

Computer algebra software gives your solution in terms of Lambert W if it hasn't found solutions in the [elemenary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).

It depends on your objectives if you accept [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W) as [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression).

You can use the *algebraic* properties (e.g. transformation rules and special values) of your closed-form solution/Lambert W.
On the other hand, a closed-form expression is a placeholder for its *analytic* representations (Wikipedia: Closed-form expression - Analytic expression), e.g. its series representations, what can help to find approximate numerical solutions/values much easier in some cases.

Lambert W solution holds for your general parametric problem. Maybe there are some elementary solutions for some special properties/values of your parameters/constants.

Your equation cannot be rearranged by applying only elementary functions if it is an irreducible algebraic equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials.
But if your equation has solutions that are [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number) is a different mathematical problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I think I will attempt to simply the expressions to obtain an easier solution for my variable.