# How can I approximate this this equation $(ax+b)\exp(-cx) = (fx+d)$ to real-number?

Tags: approximation, closed-form, lambert-w

I am solving this equation
$$(ax+b)\exp(-cx) = (fx+d)$$ using generalized Lambert W function and $a,b,c,d,f,d$ are all real-valued.

I drew this equation's graph using Matlab, and I confirmed this equation passes $0$.
But when I solve it using generalized Lambert W function, it doesn't come out with an accurate value. And I know Generalized Lambert W function solution sometimes has complex numbers. But I want to obtain only real number.

In this situation, I want to know what should I check.

Comment: Could you please describe the steps of your solution attempt using the Lambert W function? This way, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Are there any conditions on $a,b,c,d,f$? What do you mean by "passes o"?

Comment: (Almost) identical question (closed): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4772971/how-to-solve-equation-axb-expx-cxd-using-lambert-w-function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve equation $(ax+b)\exp(x) = (cx+d)$ using Lambert W function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4772971/how-to-solve-equation-axb-expx-cxd-using-lambert-w-function) after substituting $-cx=X$

Comment: a,b,c,d,f are all real-valued and "passes 0" means that this equation has real-value solution because this equation has point that 0 = this equation.

Answer (score 0):

$$(ax+b)e^{-cx}=(fx+d)$$

We see, this equation is a polynomial equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($x,e^{cx}$) and with no univariate factor. We therefore don't know how to rearrange the equation for $x$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions (operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation.

If the equation is irreducible for algebraic $a,b,c,d,f$, the equation cannot have solutions that are [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number).

$$\frac{ax+b}{fx+d}e^{-cx}=1$$

We see, in the general case, we cannot solve this equation in terms of Lambert W, but in terms of Generalized Lambert W.

a)

$x\to -\frac{t}{c}$:
$$\frac{-\frac{a}{c}t+b}{-\frac{f}{c}t+d}e^t=1$$
$$\frac{-\frac{a}{c}(t-\frac{bc}{a})}{-\frac{f}{c}(t-\frac{cd}{f})}e^t=1$$
$$\frac{t-\frac{bc}{a}}{t-\frac{cd}{f}}e^t=\frac{f}{a}$$
$$t=W\left(^\frac{bc}{a}_\frac{cd}{f};\frac{f}{a}\right)$$
$$x=-\frac{1}{c}W\left(^\frac{bc}{a}_\frac{cd}{f};\frac{f}{a}\right)$$

b)

according to theorem 3 of [Mező/Baricz 2017]:

$W_r$ is the $r$-Lambert function.

$$x=-\frac{b}{a}-\frac{1}{c}W_{-ae^{-\frac{bc}{a}}}\left(-ace^{-\frac{bc}{a}}\left(-\frac{b}{a}+\frac{d}{f}\right)\right)$$
$\ $

So we have a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) for $x$, and the series representations of Generalized Lambert W give some hints for calculating $x$.
see e.g. [Mező/Baricz 2017] section 3: "The case of one upper and one lower parameter" and theorem 3.

see also: [Interpreting/understanding the lambertW on Maple software](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4751718/interpreting-understanding-the-lambertw-on-maple-software/4751840#4751840)

[Mező 2017] Mező, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mező/Baricz 2017] Mező, I.; Baricz, Á.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)

Comment: Thank you so much. There was a mistake in substitution. But when I input this solution to Matlab, the value is not real-valued, complex-valued. I think, because of Lambert W function. $W_k$, k is not -1 or 0. When k is not -1 or 0, how can I approximate this to real-valued?

Comment: I am sorry, your solution is correct but I made a mistake during the substitution. I know this solution is represented to generalized Lambert W function. but generalied lambert W function solution sometime has complex number. But I want to real number. So if any way to solve this, could you tell me?

Comment: @SEUNGMINSIM See theorem 1 in [Mező/Baricz 2017].

Comment: @SEUNGMINSIM Could you please add some of your background/knowledge/motivs to your question to prevent closing?

Comment: Okay, thank you so much. I will add something. thank you to tell me